# If I pass layers to two Keras models and Train only one ,will both the model share weights after the former is trained

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

I tried to build a simple Autoencoder using Keras for this I started with a single fully-connected neural layer as an encoder and as a decoder.

```
> input_img = Input(shape=(784,)) 
>encoded = Dense(encoding_dim,activation='relu')(input_img) 
>decoded = Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)
>autoencoder =Model(input_img, decoded)
```

I also created a separate encoder module with the help of

```
encoder = Model(input_img, encoded)
```

As well as the decoder model:

```
encoded_input = Input(shape=(32,))
# retrieve the last layer of the autoencoder model
decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1]
# create the decoder model
decoder = Model(encoded_input, decoder_layer(encoded_input))
```

Then I trained the model

```
autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
                epochs=50,
                batch_size=256,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
```

but even if i didn't train my encoder and decoder, Those are sharing the weights of autoencoder even if I passed the layers before training. I trained only the encoder but both encoder and decoder are getting trained.

```
encoded_imgs = encoder.predict(x_test)
decoded_imgs = decoder.predict(encoded_imgs)
```

Comment: AutoEncoders does not work that way. The encoder and decoder both are trained together by optimizing the loss or the reproduction error. Then as needed we can decouple the encoder and decoder and use it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have been more careful while reading the text. 
If two Keras models are sharing some layers, when you train the first model, the weights from the shared layers will be updated automatically in the other model.

https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/

This blog illustrates the use of shared layers nicely.

https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html/